# Assume that ⟨v1,...,vn⟩ contains a spanning set of V over F. Prove that {v1,...,vn} is a spanning set of V over F.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the full question:
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0OUc.png)

I am working through some test review questions and this one has me stumped. I am not sure I am interpreting the question correctly. I originally thought this was about spans of subspaces, but we have not covered that, so I am lost. I have bounced around ideas, but the proof I have right now is:

By the definition of the F-span of ⟨v1,...,vn⟩, we know there exists {λ1v1 + ···+ λnvn : λi ∈F for all 1 ≤i ≤n} such that any v in V can be represented as a linear combination.
The definition of a spanning set is a system of vectors is spanning if any v in V can be represented as a linear combination, so clearly ⟨v1,...,vn⟩ spans V over F

This seems way too simple and I feel like I am missing something. Can someone explain?

Comment: ok thank you, I think I was overthinking it

Comment: No @geetha290krm, what he should say is 'there exists $S\subset${λ1v1 + ···+ λnvn : λi ∈F for all 1 ≤i ≤n} such that any v in V can be represented as a linear combination of elements of $S$'.

Comment: In order to avoid writing down many linear combinations, the proof can be done by contradiction. Observe that for any vectors $w_1,w_2,\ldots, w_k\in \langle v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\rangle $ we have $\langle w_1,w_2,\ldots, w_k\rangle \subseteq \langle v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\rangle .$ Assume by contradiction $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n$ is not a spanning set. Then $\langle v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\rangle $ is a proper subspace of $V.$ By the remark made in the second sentence of this comment $\langle v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\rangle $ does not contain a spanning set.

Comment: This answers your question: [Span of a subset of a vector space is the smallest subspace containing that set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396515/span-of-a-subset-of-a-vector-space-is-the-smallest-subspace-containing-that-set) because, denoting by $W$ the subspace of $V$ spanned by $v_1,\dots,v_n,$ what you are asking reduces to: if $S\subset W$ then $\operatorname{span}(S)\subset W.$