# Is there a subspace of $R^3$ of dimension $1$ that contains the vectors $v=(1,1,2)$ and $w=(1,-1,2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> Is there a subspace of $R^3$ of dimension $1$ that contains the vectors $v=(1,1,2)$ and $w=(1,-1,2)$?

I see that $v$ and $w$ linearly independent so I think that there isn't a subspace of dimension $1$ that contains both vectors. But I think that there is a subspace of dimension 2 that contains $v$ and $w$.

My question is whether my reasoning is correct and how to justify it.

Comment: Perhaps your linear algebra course has information on "dimension" and on "linear dependence".

Comment: If there *was* a subspace of dimension $1$ containing both, then that subspace could be described as $\text{span}(b)$ where $b$ is a basis vector for that subspace.  That would imply that if $v$ and $w$ were both included in that span then $v=\alpha_1 b$ and $w=\alpha_2 b$, and from here you can see that this would have implied that $v$ and $w$ should have been multiples of one another.  Since they aren't, that implies there is *not* any such dimension one subspace.  There is of course a dimension 2 subspace containing both, namely $\text{span}(v,w)$

Comment: A set of $m$ vectors in a space of dimension $n$, with $m>n$, is linearly dependent.

Comment: Another way to put the above comments is: the span of two vectors is the _smallest_ subspace containing both vectors. Since $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, the smallest such subspace must have dimension 2. See this question for understanding how the span is the smallest subspace containing the vectors: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142109/if-s-is-a-subset-of-a-vector-space-v-then-spans-equals-the-intersection?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to note that since $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ are linearly independent they span, as a basis, a subspace with dimension $2$. Therefore there isn't a subspace of dimension $1$ that contains both vectors.

Indeed if such subspace would exist with basis $\{\vec u\}$ we had

- $\vec v=a \vec u \quad \vec w=b \vec u\implies \vec v=c\vec w$

which is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that $$\det
    \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    -1 & 2\\
    \end{vmatrix}=4
$$ so the vectors mentioned are linearly independant. That means that they produce a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ of dimension $2$.